# How to highlight text without triggering click with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want users to be able to click on an element and also highlight the same element. If they click it should behave like a click but if they mousedown and select some text it should not behave like a click (since that is not a click). jQuery fires a click if you mousedown and then 1 million years later mouse up. I realize you can do:

```
$myElm.on("mousedown.tmp", function () {
    $myElm.off("mouTsedown.tmp");
    $myElm.on("mouseup", function () {
        $myElm.off("mouseup.tmp")
    }
    }); //
```

*correct for spelling and factor in other event handlers. i mean roughly speaking.*

I don't want to use a plugin.

Comment: Could you not just check in your click handler if there is text within the element selected and `return false;` ?

Comment: For some situations that would work. For me if the time between mousedown and mouseup is < 500ms it should be a click. Otherwise its not a click and the user can select/copy the text inside the element.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/wG3Qr/) solution, I hope it's what your looking for.

I'm using `mouseup()` for the highlighting of the text. And in the click event I'm checking to see if text has been selected.

```
 var selection = window.getSelection();
      if(selection == 0)
       // Click event code goes here
```

Below is the code.

```
$(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){

      var selection = window.getSelection();
      if(selection == 0)
      {
          // click event code goes here.
      }
  });
  $("div").mouseup(function(){
    document.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow"); // highlight selected text
      document.designMode = "off";
  });    
  $("div").mousedown(function(){
     document.designMode = "on"; // Turn on design mode
  });
 });
```

Comment: About the `selection == 0` condition. `window.getSelection();` function will always return an object indicating the range of text selected by the user even when there is nothing selected. So instead you could check `selection.type === 'Caret'`, which is a click event type when there is no selection.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mydate = new Date()
var downtime;

$('#div').on('mousedown', function() {
    downtime = mydate.getTime();
});

$('#div').on('mouseup', function() {
    if((mydate.getTime() - downtime) < 500) {
        //perform click function 
    }
    else {
        //highlight text
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the mouse position on mousedown. Compare it with the mouse position on mouseup. If the mouse has moved a certain number of pixels, prevent the default event.

```
event.preventDefault();
```